# How to get current authenticated user angularfire2 (angular) so that it is usable in time for class methods?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have many methods that require the currentUserId. 
I have been injecting the my AuthService getting and storing the user like so:

// AuthService code

```
getAuthorizationState() {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
}
```

// Feed Component Code

```
constructor(...auth: AuthService...) {
    this.user = this.auth.getAthorizationState();
    this.user.subscribe(
        (value) => {
            console.log('value', value);
            this.currentUser = value;
        }
    );
}

// This tends to throw an error can not get property uid of undefined
getUserFeed(uri: string): Obervable<any> {
    return this.getFeed(`feed/${this.currentUser.uid})`)
}

// So have been resorting to this 
getUserFeed(uri: string): Obervable<any> {
    this.user.map((user) => {return user.uid})
        .flatMap((currentUserId) => {
          return this.getFeed(`feed/${currentUserId})`)
         });

    }
```

**Issue** : Been having to do that with everymethod. In angularjs I remember I believer using the resolve method to help with this issue.

**Question**: Is a there an 'app global' way to get and store current authenticated user's info so it is already there when calling a method in a component or injector service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went on angular gitter and was told that the observable chain that I was doing was indeed the pattern to use. I modified it slightly and will refactor to use it in the service vs the component.

```
getHomeFeedPostsWrapper(): Observable<any> {
    return getUserId().map((user) => {
        return user.uid;
    }).switchMap((userId) => {
        return this.friendly.getHomeFeedPosts(userId);
    });
}


/**
 * Helper methods
 */

getUserId() {
    return this.auth.getAuthState().map((user) => {
        return user.uid;
    });
}
```